# [tf]different laser position for obstacle avoidance

Tags: ros, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Currently I am following this [tutorial](https://syrotek.felk.cvut.cz/course/ROS_CPP_INTRO/exercise/ROS_CPP_WALLFOLLOWING) to implement the wall following algorithm,
During the wall following stage, I need to do the obstacle avoidence.
When the laser position is puttedd on the center of the robot,
Its simple to know robot hits obstacle when one of laser range is smaller than robot radius.

But when it move front about 10cm.(because of the robot design)
It becames difficult to calculate the obstacle distance.

[different laser position.jpg](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2w48wxi6PLM01zaUNCVm5KdDQ/view?usp=sharing)

I have some simple ideas about this problem:
(1) correct every laser ray by multiple some coeffcients (sin, cos..)

- cpu loading too high?
  (2) use other senor (ultrasonic, ir...etc) and put on the side of robot
- may have some blind range?
  (3) custom a costmap to calculate the obstacle distance from robot
- resolution need to 0.5cm, is it possible?

Does anyone know how to do obstacle when laser position is not on the center of robot?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245673/%5Btf%5Ddifferent-laser-position-for-obstacle-avoidance/) by [Jam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27716/jam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-10-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-10-31**:
Were you able to compile the code from the tutorial i keep getting errors with the #i which also look very weird to me.

**Comment by [Jam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27716/jam/) on 2016-10-31**:
@gijsje170 
the code has some "style", after correction it should be fine.
ex: 
rangeslink -> ranges[i],
diffE = (distMin - wallDistance) - r -> diffE = (distMin - wallDistance) - e

**Comment by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on 2016-11-01**:
Hi thanks for your response i was able to compile the code but it just keeps driving circles maybe the FOV of my kinect is just to small with just 58 degrees?

**Comment by [Jam](https://answers.ros.org/users/27716/jam/) on 2016-11-01**:
Hi, @gijsje170 
Tutorial senario is a 360 laser on the center top of the robot. 
and calculate the distance between robot and wall,
so if your want use kinect, the kinect might be set to face wall.
also with some code modification, you should able to do wall following alg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, you may need to  check the [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) package.

> tf is a package that lets the user keep track of multiple coordinate frames over time. tf maintains the relationship between coordinate frames in a tree structure buffered in time, and lets the user transform points, vectors, etc between any two coordinate frames at any desired point in time.

For example, the origin of `base_link` frame is at the center of the robot, and the `laser_frame` is 10cm to the `base_link`. The `tf` can maintain the relationship between `base_link` and `laser_frame`. When you get the obstacle distance to the laser, you can calculate that distance to your robot center by listening to the  tf `base_link->laser_frame`.
And you can setup the tf with simple `static_transform_publisher`, for example, in the launch file, you can add this:

```
   <launch>
       <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser" args="0.1 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser_frame 50" />
   </launch>
```

And then you need to write a ROS node to listen to the tf `base_link->laser_frame` and calculate what you want.

---

Originally posted by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) with karma: 763 on 2016-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0